# Local Notification

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

I am new to iPhone application.

I have to use local notification to set the fake incoming call in my application.

Then can anybody suggest me the steps to integrate the local notification in my application.

If links or source code with explanation is available, please suggest me for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can find documentation for local notification here

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW13

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good tutorial for integrating local notifications into your application http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-local-notifications/